# jquery.kinetic.js, what are listeners for?

Tags: jquery

I'm studying javascript and jquery, in order to understand better I'm analyzing how [jquery.kinetic.js plugin](http://the-taylors.org/jquery.kinetic/) works, everything was going well until I try to do something with the listeners, in the website of the plugin, in the options section says:

> Listeners:
>
> > All listeners are called with:
> >
> > - this = jQuery object holding the scroll container
> > - a single settings argument which are all the options and { scrollLeft, scrollTop, velocity, velocityY }

Now, this is a big favor, but, If you can just tell me how to do something with this, something that I can see, it would be great! from that point I can struggle alone to understand better.

Comment: Er... what?  You were doing fine until your last sentence, which basically reads `smth`.  What is your *specific* question?

Comment: sorry! mm how can I call a listener from this plugin? is it inside the activation like this:

`$('foo').kinetic( { this.call( 'slowdown', { scrollLeft, scrollTop, velocity, velocityY } ) } );`

I'm complety lost with this.

Comment: is it even with call()?? or I need to use something else?